# Serialize List of objects fails with NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, list, serialization, clipboard

In order to support Copy/Paste in my application, I have to make all my objects serializable to be able to put them into the clipboard and get them again from there. It works as expected as long as there are no `List<xy>` objects that have to be serialized.

This is the first part on one object:

```
[Serializable]
public class Parameter : GObserverSubject, ISerializable, IObserver
{ 
    #region Attributes
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Parameter));
    private int priority;
    private string name;
    private int id;
    private string description;
    private string comments;
    private List<Value> values;
    private Container myContainer;
    private bool changed;
    private int order;
    private bool noUpdate;
    #endregion
}
```

I also implemented those two methods:

```
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("priority", priority);
    info.AddValue("name", name);
    info.AddValue("id", id);
    info.AddValue("changed", true);
    info.AddValue("order", order);
    info.AddValue("values", values, values.GetType());
}

protected Parameter(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    priority = info.GetInt32("priority");
    name = info.GetString("name");
    id = info.GetInt32("id");
    values = (List<Value>)info.GetValue("values", values.GetType());
    changed = info.GetBoolean("changed");
    order = info.GetInt32("order");
}
```

This is how I copy and paste stuff from my `TreeView`:

```
Parameter parameter = ((TreeNodeParameter)this.TestDesignTree.SelectedNode).getParameter();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(parameter);

IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
Object copiedObject = iData.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);
log.Info("type of selectednode is: " + this.TestDesignTree.SelectedNode.GetType());
log.Info("type of object in clipboard is: " + copiedObject.GetType());
```

The application crashes at `copiedObject.GetType()` with a `NullReferenceException`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the iData.GetData line, and inspect the iData object. What contents exists and for what data types? Most likely was no content for `DataFormats.Serializable` so the copiedObject will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the only problem was how I defined the type of the object:

```
values.GetType()
```

should be:

```
typeof(List<Value>);
```